# Deploy a laravel application to shared hosting and get "No application encryption key has been specified." error

Tags: php, shared-hosting, laravel-5.7

I am trying to deploy my laravel 5.7 application on shared hosting, but get "No application encryption key has been specified.". I run php artisan key:generate on my localhost and after re-deployed the application, but didn't work.

What could be wrong with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm face to the same issue but a lot search I have found a solution.
I'm not sure this is a good solution or not because I'm not a web developer,
anyway put the following code in project-name\config\app.php

```
‘key’ => env(‘APP_KEY’, ‘base64:insert key here’),
```

copy key from .env file

Answer (score 1):

If you have already run `php artisan key:generate`, then run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the configuration cache.

Comment: (And make sure `php artisan key:generate` worked properly - there should be a `APP_KEY` entry in the `.env` file.

Comment: What hosting are you using? If it's git-based, could it be ignoring `.env`?

Answer (score 0):

> I run php artisan key:generate on my localhost and after re-deployed the application, but didn't work.

`.env` is not typically (nor should it *ever* be) deployed as part of the source code. Laravel's `.gitignore` prevents `.env` from being checked into source control, as it may contain highly sensitive info that shouldn't be, say, checked into Github.

You need to run `php artisan key:generate` **on your hosting** (or upload a `.env` file to it). You'll also need to fill out the `.env` file on your hosting with other key details like database passwords - anything you've defined on `localhost` will need to be defined on your hosting, too.

Comment: Yes, OK... but shared hosting has several limitations. Most, for instance, don't provide a way to use cmd so running artisan commands is absolutely out of the question.

Comment: @clesmalo That's why `(or upload a .env file to it)` is in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you did, however, uploading the file itself is not enough because (from what I've read) you'd still need to clear the configuration cache with php artisan config:clear.
In case anyone finds this useful, you can run artisan commands through php. For example, you may create this route and visiting it would execute the config:clear command:
`Route::get('/artisan',function(){
  Artisan::call('config:clear');
  return 'Configuration cache has been cleared!';
});`

Comment: You only need to clear the config cache if you've cached the config. If you can't SSH into shared hosting, you probably haven't cached the config either, as doing so requires a command to be run.